# TextView showing strings that are not in the strings.xml when device language is changed

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

When I change the device language, strings that are not in the strings.xml are showing in my text view.

Below is my text view code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_all_activity_16"
    android:text="@string/check_document_image_readable"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
......
```

in the values/string.xml  file:

```
    <string name="check_document_image_readable">A foto ficou legível?</string>
```

My app don't support other languages (it is written in portuguese).

When I run the app withe the device set to English:
[image: original]

But if I change to Spanish (even if I kill the App):
[image]

I'm developing with Android Studio 3.0.1. This happens in the API's 24 and 25.

How can I use only the values/strings.xml for any device language?

Comment: I came across an almost identical issue. Some strings were replaced by other strange/different strings (not in my strings resources) when running the app in the emulator while reviewing other locales/languages. Solved it by uninstalling the app and installing it again. The root cause is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Android has support to [Different Languages and Cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)according to the device's language setup. You can achieve that working with different strings resource for which language that you desire to support.

In your project, right-click res/values/ and select New -> Values resource file. Enter "strings" for the file name and leave the source option set to main. In the Available qualifiers and click ">>" button to move "Locale"to the Chosen qualifiers section. Select the language that you wish to support and select the region (default is: Any region) and left-click "Ok". Android studio will automatically generate a new resource file also called "strings.xml".

Why did I mention that? Android at run time looks for a default string resource. What might be happening is that you're not using a default string resource, instead you're using a 'string-pt' resource, this would be a problem if you don't have resource string file for Spanish or other language.

Answer (score 0):

if you intend to support other languages when the user changes the default language.
you should override **string.xml** file

create another **string.xml (sp)** with Spanish as local and add your resource value

```
<resources>
       <string name="check_document_image_readable">A foto ficou legível?</string>
</resources>
```

to override string.xml with the Spanish version.
click on the res folder choose new resource file and name it **strings**.
on the left select **local** and choose Spanish